# Substitute of WP LongListSelector in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, longlistselector

I am working on porting a Windows Phone app to Windows Store and I looking for the best substitute of the WP LongList Selector. The ListView is not quite what I am looking for since it lacks some features I need:

I need to create a grouped list of items where each group has a header and a footer. Grouping and headers are no problem in ListView but footer are not supported (are they).

Is there some control for Windows Store that has the same feature set as the LongListSelector for WP? If not in the SDK maybe there is some third-party control that offers these features?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice article [Top 10 Differences between developing Windows Phone and Store apps](http://www.slideshare.net/sharpgis/top-10-differences-between-developing-windows-phone-and-store-apps) and it recommend GridView as a pair to LongListSelector. Adding footer shouldn't be a problem for GridView or even ListView, change control template and add footer as the header. There are a [lot samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780638.aspx).