# How to make fixed header in grouped listview for windows store

Tags: listview, winrt-xaml

How to make sticky group header in Windows store like grouped listview in Windows phone with sticky header?

While scrolling down through the list, the current group's header should remain visible until the next header reaches it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substitute of WP LongListSelector in Windows Store App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108709/substitute-of-wp-longlistselector-in-windows-store-app)

Comment: The name of the windows phone control you are looking to replicate is "LongListSelector" -- as seen in the "People" app